# How to convert argv[1] to LPCVOID?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a `C++` utility that accepts `argv[]` arguments. One of the arguments is to be converted and used as a memory address by a Windows API call that required this address to be `LPCVOID` according to documentation. I have attempted the following:

```
int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])

{
    if (argc < 3) {
        cout << "Arg1 and Arg2 are required.";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    LPCVOID address = (LPCVOID)argv[1];
    cout << address;

    // some other stuff here
    return 0;
}
```

However, address is not used correctly and the `cout` statement above prints the address after conversion as `01297FFA` when the `argv[1]` input is `161551C`. Any help on fixing this is appreciated.

EDIT to include the command I executed:

```
myprog.exe 161551C
```

Comment: Do you mean the address of `argv[1]` is that or the contents is that?

Comment: Can you show the command line you used when creating the process. I'm guessing that you passed the address as text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I passed the memory address as a text string representing the hex address. Edited my question to show this.

Comment: That makes the question clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the string pointed by `argv[1]` to an integer representation, and then cast the integer to an LPCVOID pointer.

Here it seems to solve the issue:

```cpp
uintptr_t u_adress;   
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << argv[1];
ss >> u_adress;
LPCVOID address = (LPCVOID)u_adress;
```

Comment: I'd advise against using `unsigned int` for storing a pointer, it will fail for 64-bit code. Use `uintptr_t` instead

Comment: Fixed the answer. Did not think of that when I saw his example address.

Comment: You can use [stoull](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) and cut your code in half: `auto const address{std::stoull(argv[1], 0, 16) };`.

Comment: @IInspectable you should use `nullptr` rather than `0` for a null pointer and with `stoull` it's best to pass in a `pos` pointer so you can check that it has parsed the whole string